# Iterate through folder on mac

Tags: vba, macos, ms-word

I have a Word macro to iterate over a specified folder's contents for Word documents. I cannot get the following function to return my Microsoft Word documents.

```
strFolder = MacScript("return (path to desktop folder) as string") & "docs:"
MsgBox strFolder
strFile = Dir(strFolder, MacID("MSWD")) 'this is the line that returns nil!!!
MsgBox strFile
```

I have documents in the specified folder, in .docx, .doc and .txt and only the text ones work when I change the `MacID("TEXT")`

I've noticed that if I save my `.docx` files as the old format of `.doc` it will work with the settings `MacID("W8BN")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so I cannot do this apparently according to the following link

http://www.microsoft-word-answers.com/microsoft/MAC-Office-Word/36053797/macro-for-combining-word-documents-into-one-converting-pc-macro.aspx

Mac osx 10.6 and above have dropped support for Type and Creator codes!

So I'm doing as the article says, only have .docx files in the directory

Answer (score 2):

If you do decide that you still need to deal with multiple file types, you could consider using a little bit more Applescript to discover the file type of each file in the folder - for a single file, you might do something based on

```
tell application "System Events"
    set p to the properties of ("Macintosh HD:Users:me:Documents:Document2.doc" as alias)
    return the file type of p
end tell
```

On my 10.6 system, .doc returns"W8BN", .docx returns "WXBN", and .docm returns "WXBM", so I would might need to find out what .dotx, .dotm etc. do.

i.e. my take is that in this case, "support has been dropped" means "it's up to you to determine the extent to which you can rely on this stuff" rather than "all related facilities have gone"

The OP commented that "I tried the function strFile = Dir(strFolder, MacID("WXBN")) and it didn't return anything"

My response was that I wouldn't expect MacID("WXBN") to return anything - the values I mentioned are returned from the Applescript I supplied. If necessary, you may be able to work around the limitations of "Dir" by using more AppleScript, probably replacing the Dir functionality completely.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I tried the function strFile = Dir(strFolder, MacID("WXBN")) and it didn't return anything.